# How do I get the Bitmap name when I click the image in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to click on an image in a datagridview and then write its image/file name into a textbox so I can access this from elsewhere.

First I try just a small app to make sure I can make it all work. A Dialog contains the dataviewgrid and I put a bitmap into it as below:

```
public ChooseFormat()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1[0,0].Value = new Bitmap(@"C:\a\eggs\grid_app\grid_app\bin\Debug\graphics\1L5HQ60.bmp"); 
        }
```

Now I click on the image but all the things I have tried I cannot get hold of the file name. The closest I get is below but this returns "System.Drawing.Bitmap" and not the file name. I am sure this must just be a tweak here to make it work but I have tried teh few things I know and nothing is working.

```
        void DataGridView1CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            txtbx_choice.Text = dataGridView1[0,0].Value.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried it with overriding the `ToString()` method of the `Bitmap`object?

Answer (score 3):

Drilling into the cells's data in the debugger doesn't bring up any info on the source of it. Maybe I have overlooked something..

One simple solution is to store the filename in the cell's Tag property:

```
string fileName = @"C:\a\eggs\grid_app\grid_app\bin\Debug\graphics\1L5HQ60.bmp";
dataGridView1[0,0].Value = new Bitmap(fileName ); 
dataGridView1[0,0].Tag = fileName ;
```

Now you can always access it:

```
string displayedFile = dataGridView1[0, someRow].Tag.ToString();
```

Comment: Adding the name into the TAG has sorted it for me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have placed a Picture Box on the same form and this how I am displaying  the ImageColumn's data (an Image ) in picture box

```
pictureBox1.Image = (Image)dataGridView1[0, 0].Value;
```